# Constraint ambiguity in disabled view's subview iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

In my `ViewController` ,I have a `tableView` designed for iphone and a `collectionView` designed for ipad.`Tableview` is disabled for ipad and collection view is disabled for iphone.BUt now I get a constraint ambiguity for a subview within `tableview` cell when size class is "any width any height".`Tableview` is disabled and is greyed out.BUt the subview cannot be disabled it seems.

how to resolve this?

[image]

Comment: Try giving subview of the cell as size class only for iPhone?

Comment: Can we do that for a single view??I think unchecking the "use size class" checkbox in storyboard will convert the entire project to a particular size class.either iphone or ipad.

Comment: I just saw a video on size classes and I believe you can do for 'compact size' ... Does this video help you? https://youtu.be/N5Ert6LTruY?t=45m